# Time is not displayed on system bar after I installed 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I installed 17.10 and clock does not diplayed on top bar

[image]

Comment: I see "Cts 22:56" right there, is this not your time/clock?  In GNOME, the time is not in the indicator bar at the right, it's in the center of the top bar.

Comment: @ThomasWard I also guessed so, that's why asked for screenshot :) I think OP is confused it's in the middle instead of the right.

Comment: @Kemal I've added this as an answer so you can mark it as accepted and therefore inidcate this question is answered.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The shift from Unity to GNOME means that the clock shows up in the middle of your top bar, and not as part of the indicators like existed on Unity.

It's right there in the center of your top bar - "Cts 22:56".  That's your clock right there.  It can be changed in the settings just like before, but it will stay in the center.